# Plotting of binary prediction in Python it's not working

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, prediction

I'm trying to plot some data for a binary model using Python but the graph it's not showing me any data and I don't understand why, I don't have errors, the code it's running very fast, the results for the binary mode it's correct, it's showing me the correct data but it's not plotting me the graphs and I don't understand why...This is my python code, i get a key error for ['acc']:

```
   #Building and Training the Neural Network
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# convert into binary classification problem - heart disease or no heart disease
Y_train_binary = y_train.copy()
Y_test_binary = y_test.copy()

Y_train_binary[Y_train_binary > 0] = 1
Y_test_binary[Y_test_binary > 0] = 1

print(Y_train_binary[:20])
        def create_binary_model():
            # create model
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=13, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

            # Compile model
            adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
            model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
            return model

        binary_model = create_binary_model()

        print(binary_model.summary())

        # fit the binary model on the training data
        history=binary_model.fit(X_train, Y_train_binary, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test_binary), epochs=200, batch_size=10, verbose = 10)

        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        # Model accuracy, here the graph it's not plotted
        plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
        plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
        plt.title('Model Accuracy')
        plt.ylabel('accuracy')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train', 'test'])
        plt.show()
        # Model Losss, here the graph it's not plotted
        plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
        plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
        plt.title('Model Loss')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train', 'test'])
        plt.show()

        # generate classification report using predictions for categorical model
        from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
        # generate classification report using predictions for binary model 
        binary_pred = np.round(binary_model.predict(X_test)).astype(int)

        print('Results for Binary Model')
        print(accuracy_score(Y_test_binary, binary_pred))
        print(classification_report(Y_test_binary, binary_pred))
```

This is how the graph it's looking right now, it's not plotting my data:
[image: Graph right now]

and this is how it should look like...:[image: expected output]

Comment: *i get a key error for ['acc']:*. Can you try it with `['accuracy']`?

Comment: @emremrah it's working, thanks <3 i m so stupid... but now I have one graph over the other, how can I make a different graph for the other plot? I need to make 2 plots, one for model loss and one for model accuracy

Comment: Afther the first plot, run `plt.clf()` to clear the last plot. Then the second one should be printed well.

Comment: @emremrah it's printing me only the second plot, the first one it's cleared... i managed to plot it to my console but I want it to plot in a window not in the console..%matplotlib inline it's working in the console only...

Comment: Ah, I see, you are right. So if you want to look two plots at once, maybe you can use subplots. Check out https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/multiple_figs_demo.html

Comment: @emremrah done it, thanks, i should modify window size because the data is overlapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually know why but I have had this error before: sometimes the accuracy in the model history is kept as `acc` and sometimes `accuracy`. It may be related the `metrics` when compiling the model. In your code it's `accuracy`, so you can try it with: `history.history['accuracy']` instead of `acc`.